# postgresql 12 and archive_cleanup_command ona primary (read/write) PostrgreSQL system vs. the standby (read only) systems

Tags: postgresql-12

I formulated a similar question with the PGPOOL-II forum, but I think my questions are more related to PostgreSQL itself.

Configuration - 3 nodes cluster (primary and 2 standby systems) with pgpool-II 4.3 and PostgreSQL 12

postgresql.conf off each systems.

shared_buffers = 1024MB

work_mem = 50MB

maintenance_work_mem = 256MB

effective_cache_size = 4096MB

max_wal_size = 2048MB

max_connections = 1000

checkpoint_timeout = 20min

checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9

autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 5000

autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 5000

autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.2

log_min_duration_statement = 3000

commit_delay = 500

max_locks_per_transaction = 512

password_encryption = md5

wal_level = replica

archive_mode = on

archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/pgsql/archivedir/%f'

hot_standby = on

max_wal_senders = 10

max_replication_slots = 10

max_wal_size=200

wal_keep_segments = 10

port = 5432

wal_log_hints = on

restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/pgsql/archivedir/%f %p'

archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/pgsql/archivedir %r'

include_if_exists = '/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/myrecovery.conf'

I understand the pgpool-II myrecovery.conf overwriting the restore_command off each standby systems.

physical slot replication is being utilize across the 2 standby systems

Our issue is that off the primary server the dedicate disk reserve for postgres keeps filling up, especially the /var/lib/pgsql/archivedir folder.

My understanding the archive_cleanup_command action is only normally perform off the standby systems and I’ve read in few articles with different views on how the archive_cleanup_command operates where physical slots are involved.

What I’ve notice is the /var/lib/pgsql/archivedir folder keeps growing to a point where the drive get full.

We can see the du -h /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_wal file in this folder get deleted (purge) when the folder size gets close to the max_wal_size size, but du -h /var/lib/pgsql/archivedir keep growing.

The way we are currently are managing the issue is by periodically performing a pg_basebackup off the primary system to a backup folder and then performing the archive_cleanup_command manually looking for the .backup file in the archivedir folder.

I did several google searches and unable to find any relevant information around this subject in relation to pgpool-ii.

What’s the proper way of managing the archivedir space off the primary system in the cluster configuration as I’ve outlined?

What’s the best practice for this area and any guidance would be appreciated ?

Hope my question make sense ...